# Making the first row in a DataTable the name of the columns

Tags: c#, datatable

I´m trying to set the first row of a DataTable to be the column names. I´m using a [GenericParsing library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/GenericParser.aspx) from Code Project. The problem is that the parser sets a default name for the columns.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a link to the parsing library?

Comment: Why do you want to set the first row as column names? There must be some property in that library classes that will allow you to specify your column names and override the default ones.

Comment: @Jason Down : I found it here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/GenericParser.aspx  is good project actually :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
DataRow firstRow = table.NewRow();
List<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    names.Add(column.ColumnName);
}
firstRow.ItemArray = names.ToArray();
table.Rows.InsertAt(firstRow, 0);
```

If the first row already exists and you want to "overwrite" this change the first line to:

```
DataRow firstRow = table.Rows[0];
```

And remove the last line.

Comment: This lines create a new row filled with the column names ...! but what i wanted is actually the opposite ...changing the name of the actual columns by importing the values form the first row ...! i can use a dummy loop but i was hopping that u have some thing more elegant for me :) ...thanks

Answer (score 18):

I think you need the following:

```cs
using System.Data;
...

foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    string cName = table.Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString();
    if (!table.Columns.Contains(cName) && cName != "")
    {
         column.ColumnName = cName;
    }
                
}

table.Rows[0].Delete(); //If you don't need that row any more
table.AcceptChanges();  //You need save the table after deleting the row
```

Comment: Of course add data.Rows[0].Delete() if you not need that row anymore :)

Comment: You already check `cName != ""` once, the second time is pointless you can change safely to `column.ColumnName = cName;`

Comment: Unless you want an error when iterating the rows you should follow `table.Rows[0].Delete();` with `table.Rows.RemoveAt(0);` to remove the deleted row from the collection

Answer (score 0):

hi hope this will help u this will make all the row as you column header

```
foreach (DataRow inRow in inputTable.Rows)
     {
         string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
         outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
     }
```